# What does "i915_program_error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups" mean and can I solve it?

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

In trying to run the game Braid, I get a black screen and a mouse cursor, which I then have to kill.

I donwloaded the game .deb via the humble bundle, ran it and software center open, dl'ed an extra 18.x Mb and said the game was installed.

I have tried numerous things, like running it windowed (/opt/braid/braid -windowed
) and with specific resolution (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55767/braid-downloaded-from-humble-bundle-3-is-not-running-on-11-04)), but it does not solve the problem. I have also tried running it sudo as suggested somewhere.

I get the same error no matter what:

> i915_program_error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups (8 out of
> 4)
>
> i915_program_error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups (8 out
> of 4)
>
> i915_program_error: Exceeded max ALU instructions (83 out of 64)

while it's running, and after killing it I get:

> X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  136 (DRI2)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  8 (DRI2SwapBuffers      )
>
> Resource id in failed request:  0x3e0000f
>
> Serial number of failed request:  158
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  158

I have

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
>
> 00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

and System Info under graphics says my driver is Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2.

I run a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10, installed on a laptop with an external monitor.

What does the error message mean, and can I solve this problem and play the game?

Kind regards, and thanks in advance for any suggestions.
-- R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors:

```
i915_program_error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups (8 out of 4)

i915_program_error: Exceeded max ALU instructions (83 out of 64)
```

indicate that Braid is trying to use a shader that exceeds the capabilities of the hardware (as exposed by the drivers). Specifically, it's trying to do 8 indirect texture samples; the hardware can do 4, and it's trying to use 83 instructions in the shader; the hardware can do 64.

Depending on how Braid is building these shaders this is either a strict hardware limitation - in which case you're out of luck - or (if it's using GLSL shaders) might get better as the Mesa shader compiler gets better at optimisation. You could try on a Ubuntu Precise LiveCD, as that will have a newer version of Mesa.

It's possible that your GPU does not have the hardware resources to run Braid.  The i945 is quite an old chip.

Answer (score 1):

I meet exactly the same error when running it on fedora x64 from the .bin setup of HIB

With some test I finaly got a very very very ugly slow game (truly unplayable) when running it with:
./braid -windowed -half -15fps -width 1024 -height 768

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Doing the same I can also get it to show some sort of title screen -- but's it's still slowly chopping away towards completion as I write this... It still get the `i915_program_error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups` error, though.